# Ubuntu starting on 0% battery every time

Tags: 19.04, wakeonlan

I had shut down my system with 100% battery, when I switched it on, it was on 0% battery. I have Ubuntu 19.04. This issue was also on Ubuntu 18. I found that it was due to Wake-On-LAN.

I disabled it using a script. But when I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04, this issue is back again. Even the `ethtool` shows Wake-On-LAN is Disabled.

Comment: Likely an old battery that is failing?

Comment: well, I removed the battery with full charge, left it overnight, next day I put it on again, charge was still 100% . So not an battery issue.

Comment: @Aravind that is incorrect. I use wol every day to start up fully shut down - not hibernated - machines.

Comment: @Aravind nope. Your network card and small parts of the pc are powered up and listening when wol is enabled. That's why it takes power to do it. https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it//

Comment: so how should I counter this problem ?

Comment: i always have a wireless mouse connector inserted into USB3.0. Is this causing a problem ?